# Do I need to Release JNI array that I modify and return?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am a bit of a newbie with JNI, and on one of the phones I tested I get errors about `ReferenceTable overflow`. I understand that this has to do with not releasing JNI/Java items in the native code.

I thought I did not need to release anything, because I use the given `jfloatarray`, replace it's values and then return the original JNI object again. I assumed this would make JNI free the object itself,since it just gets it back.

JNI Code:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_methodname(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jfloatArray data)
{
float* nativeValues = (float *)env->GetFloatArrayElements(data, 0);
doSomething(nativeValues);//overwrite the values with new values
return data;
}
```

JNI Error (Android 2.3):

```
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833): ReferenceTable overflow (max=1024)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833): Last 10 entries in JNI pinned array reference table:
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1014: 0x405f3750 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1015: 0x405f37b0 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1016: 0x405f3810 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1017: 0x405f3870 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1018: 0x405f38d0 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1019: 0x405f3930 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1020: 0x405f3990 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1021: 0x405f39f0 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1022: 0x405f3a50 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.069: W/dalvikvm(833):  1023: 0x405f3ab0 cls=[F (20 bytes)
11-28 15:00:58.074: W/dalvikvm(833): JNI pinned array reference table summary (1024 entries):
11-28 15:00:58.074: W/dalvikvm(833):  1020 of [F 20B (1020 unique)
11-28 15:00:58.074: W/dalvikvm(833):     4 of [F 28B (4 unique)
11-28 15:00:58.074: W/dalvikvm(833): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 20512 bytes
11-28 15:00:58.074: E/dalvikvm(833): Failed adding to JNI pinned array ref table (1024 entries)
```

What should I do? Copy the data values to a new `float*` and create a new `jfloatarray` with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to release array elements due to JVM marks it as "used in native code" when you get elements by `GetFloatArrayElements(..)` function.
Call `ReleaseFloatArrayElements()` for that.
Check details there:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17440

Comment: Will this still allow me to return the `data`?

Comment: The main idea: you should notify JVM that you fonoshed work with array and it can release it with GC if required. You may specify release type with `mode` parameter: 
0 -copy back the content and free the elems buffer
JNI_COMMIT - copy back the content but do not free the elems buffer
JNI_ABORT -free the buffer without copying back the possible changes